# Program not working after converted to exe by cx_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

my code works perfectly fine in Pycharm. but when it converted to exe, the program shut down soon I tried opening it.

below is my code in setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

packages = [
'pygame',
'pyaudio',
'wave',
'time',
'scipy.io',
'python_speech_features',
'os',
'pickle', 
'ModA', # ModA and ModB is other 2 py I wrote for the program
'ModB'
]
includefiles = ['file.pkl', '.\\audio\\']  # i imported a pickle file and a folder with some audio files inside
includes = []
excludes = []


setup(
    name="Project",
    version="0.1",
    options={'build_exe': {'excludes': excludes, 'packages': packages, 'include_files': includefiles}},
    executables=[Executable(script="Main.py", base=None, icon='confiture.ico', shortcutDir='Desktop')]
)
```

I used this code for another program and it works fine. Please help me out what I have done wrong. It would be a big help. great thanks~

Comment: Hey Jam, I sometimes convert my python files into exes but not using cx_freeze. I use an open source py2exe converter -> https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe And I do realize sometimes the exe created aren't workable. What I usually do is reinstall python and only install REQUIRED scripts/libraries and retry. Disclaimer though, I'm not using pycharm nor cx_freeze, just adding extra information for you.

Comment: thanks for showing me this new module. I have tried it but i got many questions for the interface even i have watched the tutorial videos. e.g. if i have extra .py created how should i import it, where to select packages... but frankly it is not bad to look for a new option.

Comment: @JamCheung One popular reason for not working EXEs is due to packers compressing exe or dlls inside by UPX or similar packers, which are not working in 100% of cases. There should be some option to disable UPX compression. Also I usually use [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/), I like it and it usually worked well. [Docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html). You just install pyinstaller once by `python -m pip install pyinstaller` and then for your script just run simple command `pyinstaller --onefile --noupx my_script.py`, result will appear in `./dist/` subfolder.

Comment: Here is a pretty complete guide https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi

Comment: Thanks all in advance. I have tried both pyinstaller and py2exe converter. both give me below error:
{Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-8

Current thread 0x0000278c (most recent call first):}

Which i have no clue what it means. I do all my codings in English. Good thing is, at least it gives me something. CX_Freeze don't

Comment: I solved the problem. thanks.

Comment: @JamCheung If your solution of the problem is interesting then if you want you may post your own answer to your question and accept it as correct answer. If you want.

Comment: I solved it by trial and error, finding that i should exclude some sklearn packages. after that, the exe program will run. but i don't know how to import folder with files inside.